# Catching and redirecting JWT token expiration in Vue.js without blocking other 401 errors in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I can't get two things to work together--something about a race condition in the way my axios promises are catching errors? Here are the details:

(1) When a user's JWT token expires, my APIs return a 401 and an axios intercept routes the user to logout.

In *main.js*

```
createApp(App)
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .mount('#app')
```

In  *routes.js*

```
import axios from "axios";
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router'
const routes = [
{  
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {requiresAuth: false}
},..]
...
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    return response;
}, error => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
        console.log('token expired',error.response)
        /* THIS WORKS BUT BREAKS THE LOGIN ERROR HANDLING */

    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

This works, except it breaks:

(2) if a user *logs in* with the wrong creds, the server login API ALSO returns a 401 and my app shows an error message.

*LogInUser.vue*

```
methods: {
    login() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch('login', {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.$router.push({ name: 'EventList' })
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
          this.error = err.response.data.detail
        })
    }
  }
```

In my Vuex store
*store.js*

```
login({ commit }, credentials) {
  return axios
    .post('//localhost:9000/api/login/', credentials)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      commit('SET_LOGIN_DATA', data)
    })
```

I can get one or the other to work (either handle the login error properly, or the JWT token expiry error properly), but not both. The axios intercept tries gets there first and tries to route the user to logout, and everything gets messed up. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved a similar problem (maybe the same?) by setting up my interceptor as a function that takes a `router` parameter and using metadata on my routes, like this:

**Interceptor.js**

```js
export default router => {
    // In your interceptor error handler callback
    if (is401 && router.currentRoute.meta.requiresAuth === true) {
        // Redirect to logout
    }
}
```

**main.js**

```js
import registerInterceptor from './path/to/interceptor.js'

// Initialize router and other stuff

// Register the interceptor in created() lifecycle method
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  created () {
    registerInterceptor(this.$router)
  },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Then when I'm defining my routes I add a `meta` property like this:

```js
// Some routes
{
    path: '/secure-route',
    name: 'secureRoute',
    component: ...,
    meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
    }
}
```

Then the interceptor only redirects if the route requires authentication. You could invert it and name the meta property `skipLogoutRedirect` and in your interceptor just redirect if `skipLogoutRedirect === false`, so you don't have to define the new `meta.requiresAuth: true` on all your secure routes, and instead only define `meta.skipLogoutRedirect: true` on your logIN route.

Let me know if this isn't clear enough and I can try add more detail.

Comment: Thank you--I can see this is the right way to do it and added auth attributes to my routes, but for some reason I cannot access `router.currentRoute.meta.requiresAuth` inside the intercept handler. >TypeError: Cannot read property 'requiresAuth' of undefined

Comment: How did you go about initializing the router and then setting up your interceptor?

Comment: I did just update the answer. See the `main.js` section again and see if that fixes it. I just realized I didn't include that detail originally.

Comment: hi! I updated q with how I initialize. I use the Vue 3 syntax, and it baffles me how I do what you wrote using the new Vue 3 initialization style.

Comment: Your interceptor will need to be defined in its own file. Then wherever you mount the Vue app itself, you can call that interceptor function and pass the router instance. *OR* it looks like you should be able to use `router` since your interceptor is defined below where the `router` was created.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it both ways. I wish I understood it but the route object is  there but it's attributes return undefined.  By 'there' I mean if you console log you get something that looks like the object but isn't real reference:
```{currentRoute: RefImpl, addRoute: ƒ, removeRoute: ƒ, hasRoute: ƒ, getRoutes: ƒ, …}
addRoute: ƒ addRoute(parentOrRoute, route)
afterEach: ƒ add(handler)
back: () => go(-1)
beforeEach: ƒ add(handler)
beforeResolve: ƒ add(handler)
currentRoute: RefImpl...```

Comment: I created a separate question for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67961892/real-reference-to-router-currentroute-object-is-not-passed-to-axios-interceptor    Maybe it is my real problem.