# Axios interceptor steals catch() path from the calling Promise in Vue.js, breaking down-stream error handling

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-router

I am trying to intercept 401 errors in axios for protected routes, but my interceptor seems to 'steal' the catch() chain away from **all** HTTP requests that return an error, as well as losing the error payload they contain (which the UI uses to display the type of error). This breaks all the down-stream component methods code are using Vuex actions to login, register, etc.

A possible related symptom is that I don't seem to be able to pass a 'real' reference to the currentRoute object to check the meta attribute for protected status. Instead I have to use `._value.` to get at the values of the route's meta property.

**main.js**

```
createApp(App)
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .provide('GStore', GStore)
    .mount('#app')
```

**router.js**

```
import registerInterceptor from '@/router/interceptor'
...
registerInterceptor(router)
export default router
```

**interceptor.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '@/store/index'
export default (router) => {
  axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    return response;
  }, (error) => {
    let requiresAuth=router.currentRoute._value.meta.requiresAuth
    if (error.response.status === 401 && requiresAuth) {
        console.log('token expired',error.response)
        store.dispatch('logout')
    }
    return error
  });
}
```

**LoginUser.js**

```
methods: {
    login() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch('login', {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password
        })
        .then(() => {
          //NOTE: this does not return an error if login fails because the axios interceptor.js changes the code path to only run through this `then` fork, but this STINKS
          if (this.$store.getters.loggedIn) {
            this.$router.push({name: 'EventList'})
          } else {
            this.error ='No active account found with the given credentials.'
          }
        })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('this is never called UNLESS I remove `registerInterceptor(router)` from the router.js')
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does `console.log(router.currentRoute)` show? And if you add `.meta` to that?

Comment: hi! It returns `undefined`. But `router.currentRoute._value.meta` returns the correct `meta` value. What is up with _value? It doesn't look like I should be accessing the property that way. The other thing is that intercept function still does not pass context back to the LogInUser component correctly--error handling when authRequired=false is still broken.

Comment: Apart from the funky _value reference path, I fixed my implementation by checking for successful vs unsuccessful login status in vuex instead of expecting a `.catch()` from the Vuex login action. I believe that the interceptor changes the return code path so that all 401s return through the `then` branch of the Vuex action promise in my LoginUser component method, whereas without the interceptor the axios error would return through the `catch` path as I originally expected. (which stinks--so something is wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your interceptor is simply returning `error` (effectively swallowing it), but it needs to be a `Promise` for the `.then`/`.catch` chaining. That is, the interceptor needs to return the result in `Promise.resolve` or `Promise.reject`:

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  return response;
}, (error) => {
  let requiresAuth = /*...*/
  if (error.response.status === 401 && requiresAuth) {
      //...

      // ignore error?
      return Promise.resolve();
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```